# What does the slash do in search queries?

Tags: support, search, user-interface

As I was searching for a question, I accidently typed a `\` at the end of my query and was surprised to find that I got more results than when I was searching without it.

The search [`[c#] showdialog enable`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+enable) yields 61 results.

The search [`[c#] showdialog enable\`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+enable%5C) yields 129 results.

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to see if this was some mysterious, advanced search operator, but I could not find any reference to `\` or `slash`, which left me wondering what this was doing.

- Multiple slashes at the end of the query don't affect the result: [`[c#] showdialog enable\\\\`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+enable%5C%5C%5C%5C) also yields 129 results.
- Same with slashes at the beginning: [`[c#] showdialog \\\enable`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+%5C%5C%5Cenable) also yields 129 results.
- `/` or `\` don't make a difference: [`[c#] showdialog /enable`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+%2Fenable) also yields 129 results.
- A space and `\` yields different results (I guess it's searching for the literal `"\"`): [`[c#] showdialog enable \`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+enable+%5C) yields 0 result.
- A `/` in the middle seems to separate the terms: [`[c#] showdialog en/able`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+en%2Fable) shows results with `en` and `able`, but not `enable` and yields 9 results.

Can someone explain how the slash at the beginning or end of a term is affecting the results?

Comment: Is it possible, that they are just characters to search for?

Comment: @Teemu that would be a novelty as symbol search never worked for the last 6 to 8 years.

Comment: There is also no backslash anywhere in the text (or even the source) of some of the hits specific to `enable\\` . My money is on it just being a bug and an employee will come back in a few days (perhaps after Christmas) with "oops, thanks, we made it more consistent now". Tangantially, did anyone ever notice you can't end text between backticks (monospaced text in Markdown) with a backslash, even if you escape it correctly?

Comment: @Luc Technically, Markdown has no such thing as "monospaced text" - the whole point is that form and function are separated, and you can _render_ the Markdown however you see fit. Backticks introduce _code-_ or _literal text_. Anyway, yes, I've noticed that, and it's very annoying!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed at some point. All the following searches now yield the same results:

[`[c#] showdialog enable`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+enable)

[`[c#] showdialog enable\`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+enable%5C)

[`[c#] showdialog enable\\\\`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+enable%5C%5C%5C%5C)

[`[c#] showdialog \\\enable`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+%5C%5C%5Cenable)

[`[c#] showdialog /enable`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+%2Fenable)

[`[c#] showdialog enable \`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+showdialog+enable+%5C)

Answer (score 7):

Well, from limited testing it appears it allows extra word characters to either end of the word **Enable** *(no longer requiring an exact word match)*.

To make it easier for comparison, take your searches and sort them the same way (by newest):

[`[c#] showdialog enable (Sort:Newest)`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bc%23%5d%20showdialog%20enable)
[`[c#] showdialog enable\ (Sort:Newest)`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bc%23%5d%20showdialog%20enable%5c)

Immediately, we see on the search containing the `\` character, as of the time of this answer there were two additional posts at the top of the list that did not show up in the first search result.

## [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53047677/5781745)

Contained 4 words that had `enable` included:

- b**Enable**
- **Enable**Window
- **Enable**s
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-**enable**window

But the first search didn't find this post, *because there were no instances of the exact word*: `enable`.

## [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49495980/5781745)

Contained 2 words that had `enable` included:

- **enable**s
- **enable**s (again)

Once again, notice that there were no exact `enable` matches, which is why your first search excluded it.

---

The mystery remains, however, as to why this phenomenon occurs. If you were to think of word boundaries (such as in regular expressions), appending the special character to the term appears to remove these boundaries. For example, in regular expressions you would be changing this: `\benable\b` to just `enable`.

*Also worth mentioning that non-word characters would still match (such as `-enable`).*

And as my disclaimer here: my testing was not conclusive. This was just my immediate observation.

Comment: I thought that too, but that doesn't appear to be the case, since the search query without the slash, returns [this result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150770/showdialog-without-blocking-caller) which only contains the match "enabled". Looks like search doesn't enforce word boundaries around the terms.

Comment: The fact that it finds a trailing s could be because of stemming. So it looks like the backslash is allowing combined words and without only stemming equivalents are found.

Comment: @eckes - The _non-slash char search_ did **not** catch a trailing `s`. The two examples in my post both had the word `enables`, but the non-slash search did not find these posts. It did, however, find the past-tense version `enabled` according to pushkin.